# Como fazer uma .dll no VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, dll

Tem alguns módulos do `VBA` que são utilizados constantemente para conexão no servidor da empresa, tem senha e precisa ficar de modo mais seguro. Uma alternativa que cheguei a verificar é usar `.dll` (tem uma que usamos).

Como faço um módulo que seja mais ou menos assim

```
sub conn_server()

    'Meu código que conecta com string de conexão no servidor, com usuário e senha

end sub
```

Teria como fazer isso se tornar uma `.dll`? Ou não tem como fazer o `VBA` se tornar uma `.dll`?

Answer (score 4):

Não é possivel criar DLL's com VBA, isso só é possivel com o visual basic (vb6) o que não recomendo à data. Por isso a sua unica solução para isolar o seu código é através de um projecto .NET.

Para isso é necessário alguns passos para funcionar tudo bem. Em primeiro lugar vais estar a criar um assembly .NET que não é compativél com tecnologia COM do VBA. Vais ter de fazer a mesma compativel.

**Passo1: Criar uma interface**

Importante: Estar anotada como **ComVisible** e com o **Guid** unico.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VBA_Sample
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("CB9CDA01-4581-4B9F-B77E-D7F5ACC7F4DD")]
    public interface IMostraVba
    {
        void metodo_teste();

    }
}
```

**Passo2: Criar uma classe concreta onde vai estar a tua implementação:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VBA_Sample
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("384A53F1-FEAC-4CFA-ABB8-D100A2E75198")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class MostraValor: IMostraVba
    {

        #region IMostraVba Members

            void IMostraVba.metodo_teste()
            {

            }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Importante: Estar anotada como **ComVisible** e com o **Guid** unico.

**Passo3: Nas propreidades do projeto tems de marcar como exposto para COM:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]